# Call to deleted constructor in interface (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

I've been given the following interface in test123_interface.h and I'm having a hard time creating a class that uses this interface:

```
class test123_interface {
public:
    test123_interface() = delete;

    explicit test123_interface(unsigned int t123_int){};
    virtual ~test123_interface() = default;

private:
    unsigned int t123_int;
};
```

In my test123.h, I have:

```
#include "test123_interface.h"

class test123 : test123_interface {
public:

    test123(unsigned int t123_int){};
    virtual ~test123() = default;

private:
    unsigned int t123_int;
};
```

and then in my test123.cpp, I have:

```
#include "test123.h"

test123::test123(unsigned int t123) {
  this->t123_int = t123;
}
```

However I can't compile due to the following error: "call to deleted constructor of 'test123_interface'"

What am I missing in my understanding such that the compiler wouldn't know I want to use the constructor that takes an unsigned int as an argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your call here:

```
test123(unsigned int t123_int){}
```

This is calling the deleted constructor. Instead, call the proper constructor, the one you want to be used:

```
test123(unsigned int t123_int): test123_interface(t123_int){}
```

If you are defining it in the cpp file, do:

```
test123::test123(unsigned int t123): test123_interface(t123_int) {
}
```

And in the header:

```
test123(unsigned int t123_int);
```

You cannot define your constructor both in the header and in the source file!

Comment: Thank you! The test123::test123(unsigned int t123): test123_interface(t123_int) in my .cpp is what I was missing. Re: header constructor: That's my bad. I was experimenting and forgot to take out the '{}' when I copied it in here.